# How exactly does PhantomData work in Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi, phantom-types

I find the concept of `PhantomData` in Rust quite confusing. I use it extensively to constrain object lifetimes in my FFI-based code, and I am still not sure whether I do it correctly or not.

Here's a contrived sample of how I often end up using it. For example, I do not want an instance of `MyStruct` to outlive an instance of `Context`:

```rust
// FFI declarations and types
mod ffi {
    use std::ffi::c_void;
    pub type handle_t = *const c_void;
    // ...
}

// A wrapper structure for some context created and maintained
// inside the C library
struct Context {
    // ...
}

// Handle is only valid as long as the Context is alive.
// Hence, I use the PhantomData marker to constrain its lifetime.
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    marker: PhantomData<&'a Context>,
    handle: ffi::handle_t,
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    fn new(context: &'a Context) -> Self {
        let handle: ffi::handle_t = context.new_handle();
        MyStruct {
            marker: PhantomData,
            handle
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Initialize the context somewhere inside the C library
    let ctx = Context::new(unsafe {ffi::create_context()});

    // Create an instance of MyStruct
    let my_struct = MyStruct::new(&ctx);

    // ...
}
```

I don't quite understand the following:

1. What exactly is this `marker: PhantomData` thing, syntactically? I mean, it does not look like a constructor, which I'd expect to be something like `PhantomData{}` or `PhantomData()`.
2. For the purposes of lifetime tracking, does `PhantomData` even care about the actual type in the declaration of `marker`? I tried changing it to `PhantomData<&'a usize>`, and it still worked.
3. In the declaration of my `MyStruct::new()` method, if I forget to explicitly specify the `'a` lifetime for the `context` argument, the magic of `PhantomData` disappears, and it becomes OK to drop `Context` before `MyStruct`. This is quite insidious; the compiler does not even give a warning. What lifetime does it assign to `marker` then, and why?
4. Related to the previous question; if there are multiple input reference arguments with potentially different lifetimes, how does `PhantomData` determine which lifetime to use?

Comment: There are too many questions in this question.

Comment: @mcarton I felt that these questions stemmed from a single gross misunderstanding of what `PhantomData` actually is, so I put them all in a single question

Comment: The Rustonomicon has a good answer to this question: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/phantom-data.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What exactly is this `marker: PhantomData` thing, syntactically? I mean, it does not look like a constructor, which I'd expect to be something like `PhantomData{}` or `PhantomData()`.

You can define a zero-field struct, like this:

```
struct Foo;
```

And create an instance of it like this:

```
let foo: Foo = Foo;
```

Both the type and the value are named `Foo`.

> For the purposes of lifetime tracking, does `PhantomData` even care about the actual type in the declaration of marker? I tried changing it to `PhantomData<&'a usize>`, and it still worked.

There is nothing special about `PhantomData` except that it is not an error that its type argument is unused (see [the source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.68.2/src/core/marker.rs.html#633)). This behaviour is enabled with the `#[lang = "phantom_data"]` attribute, which is just a hook in the compiler for this purpose.

> In the declaration of my `MyStruct::new()` method, if I forget to explicitly specify the `'a` lifetime for the `context` argument, the magic of `PhantomData` disappears, and it becomes OK to drop `Context` before `MyStruct`. This is quite insidious; the compiler does not even give a warning. What lifetime does it assign to `marker` then, and why?

`PhantomData` is there to let you tell the compiler information that it cannot infer itself, because the information is about a type that you are not directly using. It's up to you to give the compiler the correct information.

> In the declaration of my `MyStruct::new()` method, if I forget to explicitly specify the `'a` lifetime for the `context` argument, the magic of `PhantomData` disappears, and it becomes OK to drop `Context` before `MyStruct`. This is quite insidious; the compiler does not even give a warning. What lifetime does it assign to `marker` then, and why?

I'm not completely sure if I understand this question. `PhantomData` doesn't *do* anything - it's just a way to communicate to the compiler that you are using data in a certain way and it's up to you to express that information accurately. Note that, even if you express the constraints incorrectly, it is only possible to introduce memory unsafety if you also have `unsafe` code. Correctly expressing lifetimes in `PhantomData` is a part of creating a safe abstraction around unsafe code.

Comment: I was unaware of this syntax for zero-field structs, so "`marker: PhantomData`" looked like "special" syntax to me, and I believed that `PhantomData` somehow operated on the compiler level. Now I see that it is much more simple and obvious. Thanks!

Comment: @RomanDmitrienko actually, it's not much a special syntax as syntactic sugar: when you create a struct as `struct Foo;` (and not, for instance, `struct Foo {}` or `struct Foo();`), it becomes equivalent to `struct Foo {}` except that the compiler also inserts a constant `const Foo: Foo = Foo {};`.